# Python: sorting a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of lists and each list contains a dictionary. i want to sort the lists based on a key in my dict.

```
[[], [{'ceph_pk': 8L, 'deleted': False, 'user_key': u'landesk522_8', 'ceph_detail_id': 8L, 'account_title': u'logger test'}], [{'ceph_pk': 7L, 'deleted': True, 'user_key': u'landesk522_7', 'ceph_detail_id': 7L, 'account_title': u'test new'}]]
```

i want to sort it based on the key 'deleted'. Any ideas

Comment: Since you have tried something, please add the code to your question.

Comment: @Bengt, it is 'deleted' key. i want to sort so that list with 'deleted':True comes first.

Comment: i tried this. myList = [[],[{.....}],[{....}]]. newlist = sorted(myList , key=itemgetter('deleted'))

Comment: 1) Please edit your question. Don't paste code into a comment. 2) That is not valid Python: `8L` is invalid.

Comment: EastWood, if you want `'deleted': True` to come first, you'll have to sort and reverse, because `True > False`.

Comment: @LutzHorn, `8L` is valid in Python2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sort](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function takes a key and [cmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) functions which defines how the element are ordered, the easiest her I think would be to use a comparison function. You can tweak as you need.

```
lst = [[], [{'ceph_pk': 8L, 'deleted': False, 'user_key': u'landesk522_8', 'ceph_detail_id': 8L, 'account_title': u'logger test'}], [{'ceph_pk': 7L, 'deleted': True, 'user_key': u'landesk522_7', 'ceph_detail_id': 7L, 'account_title': u'test new'}]]

def compare_list(l1, l2):
    if l2 is None or len(l2) == 0:
        return 1
    if l1 is None or len(l1) == 0:
        return -1
    return cmp(l1[0].get('deleted', False), l2[0].get('deleted', False))

lst.sort(cmp=compare_list)
print lst
```

returns:

```
[[], 
[{'deleted': False, 'user_key': u'landesk522_8', 'account_title': u'logger test',
'ceph_detail_id': 8L, 'ceph_pk': 8L}], 
[{'deleted': True, 'user_key': u'landesk522_7', 'account_title': u'test new', 
'ceph_detail_id': 7L, 'ceph_pk': 7L}]]
```

Comment: this worked for me, i was trying to use itemgetter but i had an empty list so it would give an error of index out of bound.

Comment: But `key=` is usually preferred to `cmp=` for efficiency. Additionally `cmp=` has been removed from Python3

Comment: @gnibbler the logic behind cmp is easier to code and to understand. The problem with key is that if you compare elements by a key in ascending order and another key in descending order, you end-up with a very nasty piece of code ex: `return None if l is None or len(l) == 0 else not l[0].get('deleted', False)`

Comment: didn't know they dropped cmp in Python3, I barely use it, but sometimes it is useful. anyway, that's a good point

Comment: @SamyArous, Python 3 doesn't have the `cmp` parameter, but it does have `functools.cmp_to_key()` which can be used to convert any `cmp` function into something that can be used by `key`.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the empty lists from your list. Then, use the `key` argument to specify how the sorting should be done. `key` takes a function that should return the value that you want to use in the sorting. The syntax is

```
sorted(yourList, key=func)
```

`func` will receive as argument every item from your list. So, if `func` receives a list, how do you return the value of the `deleted` key?

Edit: Since you mention that you want `'deleted':True` to come first, you should use the `reverse=True` argument on `sorted`, i.e., `sorted(yourList, key=func, reverse=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `itemgetter` you will need to filter the empty list out, and also pull the dicts from the nested lists

```
>>> L = [[], [{'ceph_pk': 8L, 'deleted': False, 'user_key': u'landesk522_8', 'ceph_detail_id': 8L, 'account_title': u'logger test'}], [{'ceph_pk': 7L, 'deleted': True, 'user_key': u'landesk522_7', 'ceph_detail_id': 7L, 'account_title': u'test new'}]]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted((x[0] for x in L if x), key=itemgetter('deleted'))
[{'deleted': False, 'user_key': u'landesk522_8', 'account_title': u'logger test', 'ceph_detail_id': 8L, 'ceph_pk': 8L}, {'deleted': True, 'user_key': u'landesk522_7', 'account_title': u'test new', 'ceph_detail_id': 7L, 'ceph_pk': 7L}]
```

If you need to keep the empty list and/or the extra level of nesting, you should use a `key` function (in preference to a `cmp` function)

```
>>> def key_func(item):
...     return item[0]['deleted'] if item else 0
... 
>>> sorted(L, key=key_func)
[[], [{'deleted': False, 'user_key': u'landesk522_8', 'account_title': u'logger test', 'ceph_detail_id': 8L, 'ceph_pk': 8L}], [{'deleted': True, 'user_key': u'landesk522_7', 'account_title': u'test new', 'ceph_detail_id': 7L, 'ceph_pk': 7L}]]
```